Rotational Motion

Hi everyone. Can I ask some questions about torque and moment of inertia? In the case below, which is called "human flag" posing, when the athlete starts to lift up her body, is the torque lifting different to torque of maintaining her body?
And in the case she starts rotating around the pole, how torque and angular acceleration invovle?

Sure $\tau_{~lift} \gt \tau_{gravity}$ and when it stops, then $\tau_{~lift} = \tau_{gravity}$ and so maintaining body position requires less torque than raising it.
